# constructor returns mistake, dynamic memory c++

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <cstring>

using namespace std;
const int err=404;

class longMath{
protected:
    char* str;
    int size;

protected:
    //void create(int len);
public:
    inline longMath();
    inline longMath(longMath &a);
    inline longMath(char* s);
    inline longMath(string &s);
    ~longMath(){delete [] str;}
    void print();
};  
    //-------------------------------------------------------------//


longMath::longMath(){size=0;}

longMath::longMath(longMath &a){
    str = new char [a.size];
    strncpy(str,a.str,a.size);
    size= a.size;
}

longMath::longMath(char* s){
    size = (sizeof s)/(sizeof s[0]);
    str = new char [size+1];
    strncpy_s(str,size+1,s,size);
}

void longMath::print(){
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cout<<*(str+i);
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

longMath::longMath(string &s){
    str = new char [s.length()];
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
        *(str+i)=s[i];
    }
    size = s.length();
}

longMath longMath::operator= (const longMath &a){//оператор присвоения
    if (this==&a) return *this;
    delete [] str;
    str = new char [a.size];
    strncpy(str,a.str,a.size);
    size = a.size;
    return *this;
}

//----------additional function--------------------//
int switcher(char &c){
    switch (c){
    case '1': return 1; break;
    case '2': return 2; break;  
    case '3': return 3; break;
    case '4': return 4; break;
    case '5': return 5; break;
    case '6': return 6; break;
    case '7': return 7; break;
    case '8': return 8; break;
    case '9': return 9; break;
    case '0': return 0; break;
    default: return err;
    }
}
```

And another main file

```
# include <iostream>
# include "longMath.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char* s("regw");

    longMath h,n(s);
    n.print();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This program doesn't want to compile, it returns   exception in `0x0f8657aa (msvcr100d.dll)`

Help me with this please. Program seems like not too complicated.
There is a problem in constructor, initialized with `char*`.

Comment: If the compiler outputs an exception like "0x0f8657aa (msvcr100d.dll)" I think you have hit a compiler bug.

Comment: When you say "doesn't want to compile", do you mean "compiles fine, but does not run"? ;)  Because that error message does not make any sense coming from compiler, unless it's compiler bug, which is very unlikely.

Comment: `size = (sizeof s)/(sizeof s[0]);` is not required. Just try to use `strlen(s)`

Answer (score 2):

This could be the problem

```
(sizeof s)/(sizeof s[0]);
```

This trick only works with arrays, not with pointers to arrays.

You should add a length parameter and pass it in during construction. Or use `strlen` to find the length of the string, if it is null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing the following: sizeof(char*, a pointer) is usually 4 (on 32-bit machines), sizeof(s[0]) is just like sizeof(char) (1 byte on 32-bit machines), so you always get 4 bytes.
And if your string is longer than 3 bytes, the program will crash.
Use strlen(s) to get the length of char* s. Try it.

Comment: I have changed the constractor
longMath::longMath(char* s){
 size=strlen(s);
 str = new char [size+1];
 strncpy_s(str,size+1,s,size);
}
But still it throws an exption. What should i do?

Comment: What exception does it throw? Have you tried to debug your program and looked what is inside of "size"?

Comment: Inside size everithing is OK, i have checked.
Maybe this will help - I am thrown to block of code  /* verify block type */
            _ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));
in dbgdel.cpp

Comment: Have you checked, if **str** returns a valid pointer? Seems, that an assertion from the runtime throws the exception. Besides, try to replace strncpy_s with strncpy. Maybe that's it.

Comment: I do not know why, but after changing length in constractor it started to work str = new char [size]; I found it really strange, isn't compiler add '\0' in the end of char*? and haw this str = new char [size+1]; can give a mistake??

Comment: You need to explicitly add the terminating '\0', when you create strings that way. Only strings created like char[] str = "Hello, World" or char* pstr = "Hello World" will have a terminating '\0'. Strncpy is not respnsible for this.

Answer (score 0):

In your default constructor, you haven't allocate memory for `str` but you call `delete [] str` in destructor. Set `str` to `NULL` in default constructor should fix crash issue:

```
longMath::longMath() : str(NULL), size(0)
{
}
```

The program won't compile, because you didn't declare `operator=` in longMath class but defined it. you need to add below declaration in class:

```
longMath& operator= (const longMath &a);
```